# Print full uint32_t in hex from struct bitfield

Tags: c, io, bit-fields

I have a structure like below:

```
struct myCoolStuff{
    uint32_t stuff1 :  4;
    uint32_t stuff2 :  4;
    uint32_t stuff3 : 24;
    uint32_t differentField;
}
```

How can I combine these fields into a hex format for printing to the screen or writing out to a file? Thank you.

```
struct myCoolStuff data = {.stuff1=0xFF, .stuff2=0x66, .stuff3=0x112233, .differentField=99};

printf("my combined stuff is: %x\n", <combined stuff>);
printf("My full field is: %x\n", data.differentField);

Expected Output: 
my combined stuff is: 0xFF66112233 
My different field is: 99
```

Comment: `union` could be useful?

Comment: How do you expect to fix 0xFF into 4 bits?

Comment: Don't use bitfields and just bitmask a `uint32_t` and be done with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can't get `0xFF` out of `0xFF` after you put it in a 4-bit variable. `0xFF` takes 8 bits. Same for `0x66`.

As for reinterpretting the bitfields as a single integer, you could,
in a **very nonportable** fashion (there's big-endian/little-endian issues and the possibility of padding bits) use a `union`.

( This:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct myCoolStuff{
    union{
        struct {
        uint32_t stuff1 :  4;
        uint32_t stuff2 :  4;
        uint32_t stuff3 : 24;
        };
        uint32_t fullField;
    };
};
struct myCoolStuff data = {.stuff1=0xFF, .stuff2=0x66, .stuff3=0x112233};

int main()
{
    printf("My full field is: %" PRIX32 "\n", data.fullField);
}
```

prints `1122336F` on my x86_64. )

To do it **portably** you can simply take the bitfields and put them together manually:

This:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct myCoolStuff{
        uint32_t stuff1 :  4;
        uint32_t stuff2 :  4;
        uint32_t stuff3 : 24;
};
struct myCoolStuff data = {.stuff1=0xFF, .stuff2=0x66, .stuff3=0x112233};

int main()
{
    uint32_t fullfield = data.stuff1 << 28 | data.stuff2 << 24 | data.stuff3;
    printf("My full field is: %" PRIX32 "\n", fullfield);
}
```

should print `F6112233` anywhere where it compiles (`uint32_t` isn't guaranteed to exist (although on POSIX platforms it will); `uint_least32_t` would've been more portable.)

Be careful to make sure `data.stuff1` has enough bits to be shiftable by `28`. Yours does because it's typed `uint32_t`, but it would be safer to do it e.g., with `(data.stuff1 + 0UL)<<28` or `(data.stuff1 + UINT32_C(0))<<28` and same for the second shift.

Comment: *If you want to do it portably* [Bitfields are not portable, not in any way](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p11): "... whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined."  Just about everything about bitfields is "implementation-defined" and non-portable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Well I did mention the possibility of padding bits and put the union version in parentheses to detract from it, but maybe I should've done a better job at drawing attention to the bitwise-or + shifts solution. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Add a union inside of this struct that you can use to reinterpret the fields.

```
struct myCoolStuff{
    union {
        struct {
            uint32_t stuff1 :  4;
            uint32_t stuff2 :  4;
            uint32_t stuff3 : 24;
        };
        uint32_t stuff;
    }
    uint32_t fullField;
};

...

printf("my combined stuff is: %x\n", data.stuff);
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply (using at least `uint32_t` math) and then print using the matching specifier.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

struct myCoolStuff{
    uint32_t stuff1 :  4;
    uint32_t stuff2 :  4;
    uint32_t stuff3 : 24;
    uint32_t differentField;
}

uint32_t combined stuff = ((uint32_t) data.stuff1 << (4 + 24)) | 
    ((uint32_t) data.stuff2 <<  24) |  data.stuff3;

printf("my combined stuff is: 0x%" PRIX32 "\n", combined stuff);
printf("My full field is: %x\n", data.differentField);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help :

```
unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)&data; // store start address
int size = sizeof(myCoolStuff); // get size of struct in bytes
while(size--) // for each byte
{
    unsigned char c = *ptr++; // get byte value
    printf(" %x ", (unsigned)c); // print byte value
}
```